# POST request with ESP32 returns 301

Tags: nginx, post, http-post, esp32

I have a NGINX server on a raspberry pi. I want to send JSON file from my ESP32 board to the NGINX web-server.

In a first step, I have followed this tutorial : 
https://techtutorialsx.com/2017/05/20/esp32-http-post-requests/

It gives this code :

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>

const char* ssid = "yourNetworkName";
const char* password =  "yourNetworkPassword";

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(4000);   //Delay needed before calling the WiFi.begin

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password); 

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) { //Check for the connection
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi..");
  }

  Serial.println("Connected to the WiFi network");

}

void loop() {

 if(WiFi.status()== WL_CONNECTED){   //Check WiFi connection status

   HTTPClient http;   

   http.begin("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");  //Specify destination for HTTP request
   http.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");             //Specify content-type header

   int httpResponseCode = http.POST("POSTING from ESP32");   //Send the actual POST request

   if(httpResponseCode>0){

    String response = http.getString();                       //Get the response to the request

    Serial.println(httpResponseCode);   //Print return code
    Serial.println(response);           //Print request answer

   }else{

    Serial.print("Error on sending POST: ");
    Serial.println(httpResponseCode);

   }

   http.end();  //Free resources

 }else{

    Serial.println("Error in WiFi connection");   

 }

  delay(10000);  //Send a request every 10 seconds

}
```

No problem if I use this code with the following line

```
http.begin("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
```

My serial monitor of the ARDUINO's IDE returns :

```
201
{
  "id": 101
}
```

But, when I only replace the previous line by

```
http.begin("http://82.145.56.62:151/postfile");
```

I get on my serial monitor this :

```
301
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.10.3</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Would you have an idea of my problem ?

Thank you ,

**EDIT**

I have gone ahead a little more. I have created a php file in the directory **posts**. Now I get the HTTP code 200, so my webserver receive the POST request.

**New problem :** I cannot figure out how to display the POST content on my php file. Would you have an idea ?

Thank you,

Comment: That response has been generated from a nginx server that is probably listening on the url you are pointing out. Make sure the nginx config is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by replacing :

```
http.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
```

by

```
http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```